# How to make a 2-color background like in this wireframe

Tags: html, css

I have to reproduce this wireframe: http://www.problemio.com/wireframe.pdf

You see the narrow div that has a blue and black background and on the right side has the words "store | support | search"

Is it possible to reproduce that background in css? Or do I need an image for this?
Also, any way to tell what exactly is the html code for that blue?

Thanks!

Comment: That's an image. Open up MS Paint, draw a blue box, and then spray paint over it with the other shade of blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background on that page looks like an [repeat-x](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) of an image. You'll probably need to do something like that.

**Update**: You could use a *.png* for the "noise" and set the background color like so:

```
.menuHeader
{
    background-image:url('noise.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color: #0000FF; /* whatever you want to set the color to */
}
```

Comment: would it be an x-repeat of some image with that color scheme?

Comment: You could have a png (or some image with a transparent background) with the "noise" and then set the background-color underneath it. This would be if you wanted to be able to change the underlying color.

Answer (score 2):

O_O no... you can't reproduce that kind of random noise background in CSS. You have to use an image.  For the color, take a screenshot and open it in GIMP/MS Paint/Photoshop/most any other image editing tool and use the eyedropper to pick out the color.  The value you want is the 6 character long one like #FED2E6 or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

It won't be possible to create such a complicated pattern in CSS alone, you'll need to use an image.

It's a bit tricky to know what you mean by the 'blue' colour in the image as there are probably quite a few different shades of blue in there. If you've got access to a copy of Photoshop open the PDF up and use the colour picker to get the blue you want.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to reproduce that background in css?

It could possibly be a CSS3 pattern. Here are some **[nifty examples](http://leaverou.me/css3patterns/)**. But as others have said, there's a lot of random noise in that background, so it's most likely an image.

> Also, any way to tell what exactly is the html code for that blue?

Yes, if you have a program like Photoshop or Gimp, you can use a color picker to get the hex code of any pixel you want.